# How would I achieve encryption/decryption for users, while also having the ability to decrypt everything serverside

Tags: node.js, swift, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm not entirely sure if I should be encrypting data server side or client side to begin with. The data is a json object of some user input. What I need to be able to do:

a) encrypt data at rest [in dynamoDB]

b) decrypt data and send it back to the user when they request it

c) decrypt the entire database to run analytics and ML

**First Approach**

1)Send the newly inputted user data through HTTPS, then encrypt it server side before it hits the database (in a lambda function). Now the data is encrypted at rest.

2) When a user makes a GET request, have a lambda function that decrypts it before returning it to the user

3) simply run a decryption on the database with the same technique

I'm not sure if this is good or bad, what type of encryption to use, etc.

EDIT: I will be doing server side encryption. If anyone has any suggestions/guides on a simple but good way to do it, perhaps using some npm package, that would be great.

Comment: It does not seem like your second approach works since you have a requirement that the server can decrypt the data itself for analysis purposes.  Plus HTTPS is significantly better protection for data in transit than client-side encryption sent over HTTP because HTTPS has many other protections and it is very difficult to secure client-side encryption keys (thus why SSL/TLS uses public/private key cryptography to exchange credentials securely).

Comment: yes this is what I as thinking as well. I've read there is a way to do client side encryption, send it over HTTPS, and also decrypt it though. Having said this, do you have an ecryption/decryption suggestion if I'm using node? Should there be a master key, and if so, where would you store it?

Comment: If you're sending over HTTPS and intend for the server to be able to descrypt, then there is simply no reason to do client-side encryption before sending.  You might do client-side encryption if you were storing it client-side (in local storage or in cookie), but no need to encrypt before sending over HTTPS.  I'm not an expert on best way to do encryption in a database so I cannot answer that part (which is largely why I'm commenting on the parts I can help with, not providing an answer to the whole question).

Comment: Makes sense, I appreciate the post. I will definitely be doing server side encryption. Thank you @jfriend00. If anyone can point me in the right direction for server side encryption, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: There appear to be some good articles in a Google search for "database encryption".  You can use this to start your learning process.  Here's one: [A basic encryption strategy for storing sensitive data](https://www.itworld.com/article/2693828/data-protection/a-basic-encryption-strategy-for-storing-sensitive-data.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1: Encrypt server side or client side?**

The only advantage of client-side encryption would be performance: remove the burden of your server from doing this work, pass it off to the end user machine.

However, there is a very big disadvantage: security.  If you are encrypting everybody's data with the same key, then now everybody has access to that key, because it needs to be delivered to the client for decryption.  You have entirely defeated the purpose of the security, because the cryptographic key now lives everywhere.

What about encrypting every user's data with different keys?  That's a can-of-worms question, because you need to then consider where you are storing all the cryptographic keys.  If it is in the same database as the data, you have again defeated the purpose of encryption -- putting the keys and data together is a no-no.  You can come up with arbitrary solutions around this, but I assure you there are many considerations and you are inviting a lot of complexity.

**Question 2: Is your approach reasonable?**

Yes it is, but you need to understand what you are protecting against.  Encryption at rest mainly protects a database (including backups) provided that the encryption key never gets put in the same place as the database.  Managing the encryption key is something that needs to be carefully considered.  There is [good guidance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321320735) on that if you care to research it, but it really is the task of a security architect to design this right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AES encryption using cryptojs.
Hit the server to get key for using in encryption process.

```
        let AES = CryptoJS.AES()

        // AES encryption
        let encryptedUsername:String! = AES.encrypt(secretMessage: (username_tf.text)!, secretKey: REQUESTKEY!)
        let encryptedPassword:String! = AES.encrypt(secretMessage: (password_tf.text)!, secretKey: REQUESTKEY!)
```